# How to replace SQL queryString with HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, jdbctemplate

I am attempting to use a HashMap to hard code values instead of using a query.

Here is the ‘working’ code and SQL that returns objects of type person through a ParameterizedRowMapper.

```
Public List<Personnel> getPersonnel (long id) {

LinkedList<Long> arg = new LinkedList<Long>();
String query = null;
SimpleJdbcTemplate template;
…
…
…
query = "SELECT p.id, p.name, e.emp_type
"FROM " Personnel p, EmployeeType e"
"WHERE p.id = ? ";
args.addLast(id);

return (template.query(query.toString(),
       this.personnelRowMapper(), arg.toArray()));
```

**Personnel Row Mapper**

```
private ParameterizedRowMapper<Personnel> personnelRowMapper()
  throws SQLException
{

    ParameterizedRowMapper<Personnel> map;

    map = new ParameterizedRowMapper<Personnel>()
    {

        public Personnel mapRow(final ResultSet rs)
          throws SQLException
        {

            Personnel personnel= null;

            personnel = Personnel.Factory.newInstance();
            personnel.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            personnel.setFirstName(rs.getString("Fname"));
            personnel.setMiddleName(rs.getString("MName"));
            personnel.setLastName(rs.getString("Lname"));

            return (contact);
        }
    };

    return (map);
}
```

Here is the code that uses HashMap instead of query.

```
Public List<Personnel> getPersonnel (long id) {
List< Personnel > fb = new ArrayList< Personnel >();
HashMap<String, String> rs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        rs.put("Fname", "John");
        rs.put("Lname", "Stoops");
        rs.put("Mname", "K.");

String val1 = (String)rs.get("Fname");
String val2 = (String)rs.get("Lname");
String val3 = (String)rs.get("Mname");

//these 3 lines give me errors
fb.add(val1);
fb.add(val2);
fb.add(val3);

return fb;
```

Here are my errors: “actual and formal argument lists differ in length”
“actual argument String cannot be converted to Contact by method invocation conversion”

How do I return a List of Type Personnel using HashMap instead of SQL?

Comment: fb is a list of `Personnel` whereas `val1` is String. I would think you cannot add  `val1` to fb.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  Created a new Instance of Personnel. Then set and get the data all out once.